# Tagging AWS glue tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, boto3, aws-glue

I wanted to know if tagging of tables is possible in aws glue in any way. I know that in documentation , it is not given that it is possible for tables.  It also is given that the tagging of a database is also not possible but I was able to do so using tag_resource boto3 call as specifed in [this link.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-boto3-to-add-tags-in-aws-glue-resources)
This is the error I am getting if I try same tagging a table.

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInputException: An error occurred
> (InvalidInputException) when calling the TagResource operation

Just wanted to double check to see if it is not possible or I am missing something here.

Comment: What command are you running trying to tag a table?

Comment: response = glue_client.tag_resource(ResourceArn= resource_arn,TagsToAdd=tags_dict)

Comment: what is `resource_arn`?

Comment: arn:aws:glue:region:account-id:table/database name/table name

Comment: @luk2302  any workaround that you can suggest?